# document.getElementById().focus() returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="endDateEditBox" value="" style="margin-left:5px; height:18px; width:70px; vertical-align:middle;" onchange="validateDate('endDateEditBox', $(dateFormatErrorString).value)">
```

And I am trying to make this focus using the following Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("endDateEditBox").focus();
```

Which chrome console and Firebug both return as undefined. I feel like I am missing something very obvious here, can anyone help?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `focus()` method does not **return** a value. It sets the focus on the matched input, and then returns `undefined`...

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for that. Something to note is that if you run this from the console then the input doesn't actually get focused which is why the undefined return was confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript native focus function doesn't return anything.

If you expected to receive the element and use it in concatenation, you're probably confusing it with the [jQuery's focus function](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function setFocus()
{
    document.getElementById("endDateEditBox").focus();
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="setFocus()">
    <form>
        Date: <input type="text" id="endDateEditBox"><br />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Next time if you don't know how to format something, just click on the question mark above the text field and then on the topic you want to learn about. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/markdown#code